# MOD Notice: Farewell BYBE and hello Simon Hayter

Tags: discussion

Over the past couple of weeks I have been recovering from a rhinoplasty surgery on my nose from a collapse in the nasal passage, long story short... I'm better! and pumped with motivation.

After laying in my bed for several days I have been thinking about Pro Webmasters among many other things, I have carefully taken the decision to retire the username BYBE and use my real name across several networks.

I believe this decision will benefit myself and the communities I interact with, because it puts a name to the face and not hiding behind my business name. Anyhow... just a little post to let the regulars aware.

Comment: Hello (the real) Simon! :) (Heck, I'm still a cr*ppy _username_.) It's good that SE allows you to easily change your username, but what happens to all the `@`s?

Comment: I was thinking who is this Simon fellow putting things on hold all of a sudden... well I may be slow at times... Welcome!! BTW- I liked the name BYBE just fine. I know that some like to be private and for me I am too old to want to capitalize on a brand necessarily and I stay away from social stuff except for here. But for the young who are doing good things in the world like you are, I say be proud of who you are and let your light shine. It will pay dividends! So Simon, let your light shine!! I am glad to see it!

Answer (score 11):

Welcome to the real name club!

Comment: Couldn't have said it any better ;-)

Comment: @JohnConde Can I join the real name club? I use my first name and last initial.

Answer (score 4):

BYBE?

I always thought it was [BYOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BYOB) (which is what I do when answering questions anyway).